# How is the MTF determined of a telescope?

Tags: optics

The Modulation Transfer Function (MTF) of an optical system if often determined with the use of a MTF chart ([image](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiu_OeI0fzKAhXsAJoKHbwkC9IQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.reduser.net%2Fforum%2Farchive%2Findex.php%2Ft-35247.html&psig=AFQjCNHPB7uRhiHVkipJ-JqcDcVKWg3M-Q&ust=1455724111726776)) or something similar. This chart has to be in focus in order for it to be used.

But that made me wonder how these charts are used with telescopes (or microscopes). Since the image is only in focus with a telescope when the incoming light-rays are parallel (the object is in infinity). This would mean that if a MTF chart is used to determine the MTF of a typical telescope, they would have to place the chart at a distance of, let's say, ~200m or further. This doesn't seem very practical to me.

There must be some practical way to determine the MTF of a telescope without using a MTF chart. But I can really think of a method to determine it in a different way. First I was thinking of an sharp object (a knife for example) blocking light of a parallel bundle of light. But this would cause diffraction patterns at the edge of the knife, so it wouldnt result into a sharp edge.

Therefor my question to you is; what is used in practice to determine the MTF of a telescope?

Comment: Astronomy doesn't often use the term "MTF." [Wikipedia tells me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transfer_function) it's the magnitude of the Fourier transform of the *point spread function*, and the PSF *is* discussed often. Can you confirm if you agree with these definitions?

Comment: Alright, so they image a point on, for example, the imaging sensor which will be fourier transformed? Is this imaging of a point done by a laser? Or is this done differently?

Comment: An interesting question that I've just wasted hours searching optics journals about. As far as I can tell, the MFT of the mirror is normally measured in the lab using some rather large optics and expensive optics. The normal methods are to calculate it from the Fourier transform of a line spread function generated from a knife edge. It can also be calculated by measuring an interferogram. This is then combined with the measured MTF of the sensor to give the telescope MFT. You can also use a star to give the PSF and calculate it from there. This will be affected by the atmosphere though.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! So if I understand it correctly, you could use a collimated beam (which a large enough diameter) and project a knife edge into the aperture of the optical system. Which results into an edge spread function which is transformed to a line spread function. The Fourier Transform of this function will result into the MTF of the entire optical system.